# How can i merge an array of objects with with a unique key?

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures

I have the following array of objects.I want to merge these objects  with month as a unique  id.

```
[
  { month: 7, openSlot: 9, confirmed: 0, requested: 0, total: 0 },
  { month: 5, openSlot: 0, confirmed: 6, requested: 0, total: 0 },
  { month: 7, openSlot: 0, confirmed: 0, requested: 0, total: 17 }
]
```

The above array should be merged like this

```
  { month: 7, openSlot: 9, confirmed: 0, requested: 0, total: 17 },
 { month: 5, openSlot: 0, confirmed: 6, requested: 0, total: 0 }
```

I need to combine all the data's into every unique month. For example , on month 7 I need to do a add operation on openSlot, confirmed, requested , total

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `node.js` and `typescript`? There's nothing in your question that would be specific to these two "environments"

Comment: Using `groupBy` and `reduce` methods on the array should do the trick

Comment: Try writing some code to achieve it yourself and be more specific on the logic of this merge (ex: why confirmed would be 6 for month id 7?).

Comment: Hard to determine whether you want to simply take the highest value of a duplicate month and compress them into a single element, or whether you want to just perform additions with these values before you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using `forEach` and adding the values of each key. NB: if you are interested in a more optimized code, use the solution by [@Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70509885/1188322)

```js
const data = [
  { month: 7, openSlot: 9, confirmed: 0, requested: 0, total: 0 },
  { month: 5, openSlot: 0, confirmed: 6, requested: 0, total: 0 },
  { month: 7, openSlot: 0, confirmed: 0, requested: 0, total: 17 }
]

function merge(data) {

  let tempObj = {};

  data.forEach(item => {

    if (tempObj[item['month']]) {
      let temp = {}
      Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {

        temp[key] = key === 'month' ? value : value + tempObj[item['month']][key];

      })
      tempObj[item['month']] = temp

    } else {
      tempObj[item['month']] = item
    }

  });

  return tempObj;
}

console.log(Object.values(merge(data)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could separate `month` from the object and add all other values by their key.

```js
const
    data = [{ month: 7, openSlot: 9, confirmed: 0, requested: 0, total: 0 }, { month: 5, openSlot: 0, confirmed: 6, requested: 0, total: 0 }, { month: 7, openSlot: 0, confirmed: 0, requested: 0, total: 17 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { month, ...o }) => {
        r[month] ??= { month };
        Object
            .entries(o)
            .forEach(([k, v]) => r[month][k] = (r[month][k] || 0) + v);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```